# Excel VBA Index/Match function not working when indexing another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a template that fills certain cells with sales data from another workbook but the other workbook has a new name for each month. When I try to assign a variable as the workbook name so that it finds it each time, I can't get the index/match function to work. Not sure where the error is but is the point where the VBA script fails...

```
Sub GetNetSales()

    Dim Period As String
    Dim NS As Workbook
    Dim Can As Workbook
    Dim BookName As String
    Period = Range("Per").Value

    Set Can = ThisWorkbook

    ChDir "C:\Users\dlibby\Documents\" & Period
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\dlibby\Documents\" & Period & "\Net Sales " & Period & ".xlsx"


    Set NS = ThisWorkbook

    Can.Activate
    Range("C10").Select
    ActiveCell = _
        Application.IfError(Application.Index(NS.Sheets("CM Sales").Columns("E:E"), Application.Match(Can.Range("H10").Value, NS.Sheets("CM Sales").Columns("A:A"), 0)), 0).Value
    Range("C10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C11:C12").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C16:C22").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.Calculate

    Range("C10:C12").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("C16:C22").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: The Application.IfError part is not helping you get the correct value there, but that might not be the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I am using Index/Match in Macro I am typing formula like this:

```
Folder = Sheets("Overview").Range("F4")
filename = Sheets("Overview").Range("G4")
filetype = Sheets("Overview").Range("H4")
tabname = Sheets("Overview").Range("I4")
style = Sheets("Overview").Range("J4")
SAPsizecode = Sheets("Overview").Range("K4")

  ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDEX('" & Folder & "\[" & filename & filetype & "]" & tabname & "'!$" & SAPsizecode & ":$" & SAPsizecode & ",MATCH(C2,'" & Folder & "\[" & filename & filetype & "]" & tabname & "'!$" & style & ":$" & style & ",0))"
```

And this works for me. I think the problem in your code is how you are assigning the workbooks. With the approach above you don't need to open another workbook.